# Is there a Pythonic way to run async task in background similar to using a contextmanager?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, contextmanager

Recently I wanted to run some asynchronous tasks in the background while running other tasks but I didn't think the code was ***Pythonic*** enough:

```
task = asyncio.create_task(long_task())
await short_task()
await task
```

So I made it more ***Pythonic***:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def run_in_background(coro):
    task = asyncio.create_task(coro)
    yield task
    await task


async def main():
    async with run_in_background(long_task()):
        await short_task()
```

Does something like this already exist? If not is this considered more Pythonic or less Pythonic than the existing way?

Comment: Taking something that's short and does the job and converting to to something larger and more complex is definitely not Pythonic.

Comment: @Keith How is it larger and more complex? 2 lines against 3.

Comment: @Keith It's the same as using `with open("file")` vs `file.open` `file.close`.

Comment: Well, you've add a decorator and a `yield` before the await due to how the decorator works. Anyway, some of us prefer the [curio](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#the-big-question-why) way. :-)

Comment: @Keith Yes, but that is the implementation, I wrote it once and then I can use it anywhere. If there is an existing way like this, I wouldn't need to write a new function. Seems like you have missed the point of my question.

Comment: It was just a general observation. The question is actually vague, since "Pythonic" is also somewhat subjective, and you don't actually run a task "in the background" in an async framework. It's just part of the event loop and could block it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) provides a better way to do this with nursery objects:

```
async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    nursery.start_soon(long_task)  # Task will run in background

    await short_task()
    # Wait for background tasks to finish
```

Answer (score 5):

> Does something like this already exist?

Not at the moment, but it's a very useful idea. A more general version of the concept will be added to <strike>Python 3.8</strike> a future Python version in the form of a [`TaskGroup`](https://speakerdeck.com/1st1/asyncio-today-and-tomorrow?slide=43) class inspired by prior art in [Curio](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#TaskGroup) and [Trio](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/#nurseries-a-structured-replacement-for-go-statements).

I would suggest enhancing the implementation to use `finally`, providing a guarantee that the background task will be awaited even in case of exception; for example:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def run_in_background(coro):
    task = asyncio.create_task(coro)
    try:
        yield task
    finally:
        await task
```

> If not is this considered more Pythonic or less Pythonic than the existing way?

This part of the question is obviously opinion-based, but I would say a context manager is more Pythonic because it *ensures* that the background task is done and awaited by the time the block is left. It also ensures that the exceptions in the background task [*do not pass silently*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), which is a frequent source of bugs in asyncio code.

Comment: Thanks! Can't wait for python 3.8!